# How Best to Install a Configuration File Archive?

Tags: automation, archive, preinstallation, configuration-management

What tools exist for installing a configuration file archive in one go?

That is, having first booted a fresh Ubuntu installation, being faced with its set of default configuration files, and having an archive (loosely defined, either an uncompressed directory or single archive file) of the configuration files to install, how does one best write that archive to the new machine?

I have a small set of Bash scripts to automate installation, but am focused on the specific step of writing a configuration file archive instead of iterating either a find command through the archive, or a list of paths.  I've been fiddling with expanding a tar archive to root, and have seen some references to using dpkg.  I also recently saw a reference in passing, to a specific CLI utility that does just this without the need for an intervening tarball or .deb package but now can't seem to track it down.

Rather than reinvent the wheel, it seemed best to inquire about the best approach.  An hour or more on Google only returns posts concerning restoring default configuration files, not replacing them wholesale.

Obviously, this is intended for a single machine or small set of machines, either reinstalling on an existing machine or moving to another, and not on a scale to justify Ansible, puppet, or similar tools.

Obviously also, this is more of a meta-question about best practices and getting pointed to the right tools, not necessarily their syntax, which I can figure out.

Thanks for any thoughts.

EDIT:  The configuration files in question are just basic things needing to be sprinkled into the right places on the filesystem, and include network units, other units, and files related to ssh, rsyslog, logrotate, samba, grub, bashrc, nanorc, udev, etc.

Comment: "Small set of machines" is big enough for Ansible. It's not like you need to set up a Rube Goldberg system to run it; just Ansible on the controlling system and SSH keys for authenticating to the target systems. I do it for literally one system - a pi at my home, so that every time I wipe the pi and start again, I can just run the playbooks and have most of my setup restored.

Comment: I even have a playbook for imaging the Pi's SD card and adding my SSH keys to it, so essentially the whole routine for me becomes - move card from Pi to PC, run imaging playbook, move card from PC to Pi, run the setup playbooks.

Comment: @muru, I take your point and it does sound as if Ansible may be the best approach to this problem/task going forward.  This said, getting keys set up on the target system is essentially the same chore I'm facing here.  That requires networking and sprinkling some config files into the right places on the target's file system.  Even your approach would benefit from being able to unpack a configuration archive on the target system, if only to get it configured sufficiently for headless config via ssh, if I understand your setup correctly.  Configuring the target to be configured, as it were.

Comment: My approach handles the configuration for SSH while imaging the SD card, so no benefit for me (I won't image the SD card that Pi is using on the Pi itself - that's just way too risky). You could make a customized live ISO, or use preseeding, or use cloudinit to get this initial configuration done. For example, in a previous job, we used to have USB disks with GRUB configuration modified to boot the system with a preseed file, which would then handle user creation and whatever other minimal configuration. Perhaps you should add what exactly it is you're trying to configure in the question.

Comment: @muru, I'll make the edit but it's just basic stuff (network units, other units, ssh, rsyslog, logrotate, samba, grub, bashrc, nanorc, udev) and no different conceptally than just installing network and ssh on your pi card.